# It's about leap Year of Buddhist Era in Dataset

Tags: datatable, dataset

I have a Date time of Buddhist Era (29/02/2555) That is the leap year In Thai but in Chris isnot so when i assign into Data set. Its work for Buddhist Era ? How can i setting the format of Date time Data set for Buddhist Era ?

Answer (score 2):

Unsure what platform you're talking about, but handling those dates in C# is pretty straight forward as long as you convert to and from DateTime using the correct cultureinfo;

```
var buddhistCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("th");
var seCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("sv-se");

// Parse a date from Buddhist Era into a DateTime
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("29/02/2555", buddhistCultureInfo);  

// "date" here contains the correct date

// Output as Buddhist Era ("29/2/2555 0:00:00")
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString(buddhistCultureInfo));              

// Output as Swedish date ("2012-02-29 00:00:00")
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString(seCultureInfo));
```

As long as you convert to/from DateTime using a similar method, DataSets should have no problems containing the DateTime.